Associate branches with python virtual environments
PyCharm's is able to automatically recognize a .venv directory and use it as a runtime for a project when the project's structure is like this:
project\
    .venv\

However, the single .venv does not support switching branches to ones that use different packages.
Do you know whether there is a way to tell PyCharm to use a different .venv when I switch a branch so that I don't have to recreate them each time?
